# HDD to SSD - should I fresh install Win 10?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd

I am going to migrate from HDD to SSD. (HDD will stay as media storage)
Running Windows 10 Pro with November updates.
My motherboard doesn't support AHCI.
Should I fresh install Windows 10 in new SSD ?
or
Just clone the HDD to SSD ?

Comment: If your Motherboard does not support ACHI you will not get the full SSD speed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you should fresh install. After a while Windows will collect up random files, or even lose them. I've heard of people finding half a GB of files on their computer that hadn't been touched by anything for years. Also even you could have had some files you had lying around thinking that you might use later (I personally do that all the time).